# Nethereum C# Unit Test GetTransactionCount

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ethereum

Nethereum uses an Async method to get the `TransactionCount` of an address.

I have put the method into a async task:

```
public  async Task<object>  GetTxCount(string address)
{
  return await web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionCount.SendRequestAsync(address).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

And attempting to test it with...

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethodAsync()
{
  string address = "0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae";
  EthTest.Eth et = new EthTest.Eth();
  var encoded = et.GetTxCount(address);
  encoded.Wait();     
}
```

How should I call the `GetTxCount` from a unit test to get the actual result.

I have used the "wait" command even though it is not recommended, but still cannot get it to return a result.

The Unit test bombs out - it does not even hit the API that Nethereum calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already made the test async then use async all the way through by using await to call `GetTxCount`

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethodAsync() {
    string address = "0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae";
    var et = new EthTest.Eth();
    var encoded = await et.GetTxCount(address);
}
```

Given that `GetTxCount` is just returning the task then there really is no need to await it in the method.

Refactor to

```
public Task<HexBigInteger>  GetTxCount(string address) {
    return  web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionCount.SendRequestAsync(address);
}
```

or

```
public async Task<HexBigInteger>  GetTxCount(string address) {
    var result = await web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionCount.SendRequestAsync(address).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result.
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)